# Iterating or get Object property

Tags: php, object

My object property contain colon. That's why I am getting error. Is there any way to get this object by index value?

I have tried with this code:

```
$list_item = $obj->headers:Httpful\Response\Headers:private;
```

```
Httpful\Response\Headers Object
(
    [headers:Httpful\Response\Headers:private] => Array
        (
            [date] => Mon, 07 Oct 2019 07:25:52 GMT
            [content-length] => 0
            [location] => https://c6dftg152.caspio.com/rest
            [set-cookie] => AWSALB=OJXEha3NDEWrcMViNgTh0MvF3dP+0UlAyyVujqV7WtEv5B5t2dsBOn8Tjq3jqpovfvE3S4R7vgRZz0rkLeM1tAmComu7+7Ojj/b+rpB7O2DFxlC8zpSn7TKh2uwv; Expires=Mon, 14 Oct 2019 07:25:52 GMT; Path=/
            [server] => Caspio Bridge
            [x-caspio-request-id] => 02DE506E-540D-42F5-93DF-AF8069D9A69E
            [p3p] => CP="CAO PSA OUR"
            [x-xss-protection] => 1
            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
            [access-control-allow-headers] => Cache-Control, Authorization, Content-Type
            [access-control-allow-origin] => *
            [access-control-allow-methods] => OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
            [strict-transport-security] => max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
        )

)
```

I want to access the array elements.

Comment: That's not a colon in the property name. It means that the property is declared `private`, which means it can only be accessed by class methods.

Comment: Check the documentation of the class to see how you're supposed to access headers.

Comment: Ok got it. thank you.